# Changing height 100% to 724px makes a difference

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I've got a layout for a web app and have been trying to work out why iScroll-4 (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) seems to conflict with the JQuery animate function. Turns out, however, that it doesn't. The problem is the CSS height value of a containing DIV.

My HTML and CSS follow for an landscape orientation, iPad Settings App style web app. The right hand panel should slide left after 5 seconds, but changing the viewport DIV style to have height:724px breaks this.

I wonder if anyone can tell me why changing the commented line in the stylesheet makes a difference, please?

The following HTML references version 1.7 of JQuery and verison 4 of iScroll.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>orientation and device detection in css3</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="iphone-portrait.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="iphone-landscape.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="ipad-portrait.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="ipad-landscape.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 800px) and (device-height: 1184px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="htcdesire-portrait.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (device-width: 800px) and (device-height: 390px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="htcdesire-landscape.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 1025px)" href="desktop.css" />

    <script src="jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="iscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function slide() {
            $("#content").animate({left: -724});
        }
        setTimeout("slide()", 5000);

        var scrollNav, scrollList, scrollBody;

        function loaded() {
            scrollNav = new iScroll('navcontainer');
            scrollList = new iScroll('listcontainer');
            scrollBody = new iScroll('articlecontainer');
        }

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page" class="flip">
        <!-- navigation -->
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="navheader" class="header">page.nav.navheader</div>
            <div id="navcontrols" class="controls">page.nav.navcontrols</div>
            <div id="navcontainer" class="container">
                <div id="navscroller" class="scroller">
                    <div id="navpulldown" class="pulldown">
                        ...navscroller.navpulldown
                    </div>
                    <ul id="navitems" class="items">
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.1</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.2</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.3</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.4</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.5</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.6</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.7</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.8</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.9</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.10</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.11</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.12</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.13</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.14</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.15</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.16</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.17</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.18</li>
                        <li class="item navitem">...navscroller.listitems.navitem.19</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="navpullup" class="pullup">
                        ...navscroller.navpullup
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="navfooter" class="footer">page.nav.navfooter</div>
        </div>
        <!-- main content -->
        <div id="viewport">
            <div id="content">
                <!-- list -->
                <div id="list">
                    <div id="listheader" class="header">page.content.list.listheader</div>
                    <div id="listcontrols" class="controls">page.content.list.listcontrols</div>
                    <div id="listcontainer" class="container">
                        <div id="listscroller" class="scroller">
                            <div id="listpulldown" class="pulldown">
                                page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listpulldown
                            </div>
                            <ul id="listitems" class="items">
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.1</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.2</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.3</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.4</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.5</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.6</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.7</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.8</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.9</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.10</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.11</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.12</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.13</li>
                                <li class="item listitem">page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listitems.listitem.14</li>
                            </ul>
                            <div id="listpullup" class="pullup">
                                page.content.list.listcontainer.listscroller.listpullup
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="listfooter" class="footer">page.content.list.listfooter</div>
                </div>
                <!-- article -->
                <div id="article">
                    <div id="articleheader" class="header">page.content.article.articleheader</div>
                    <div id="articlecontrols" class="controls">page.content.article.articlecontrols</div>
                    <div id="articlecontainer" class="container">
                        <div id="articlescroller" class="scroller">
                            <div id="articlepulldown" class="pulldown">
                                page.nav.navcontrols.navcontainer.navscroller.articlepulldown
                            </div>
                            <div id="articlebody" class="bodycontent">
                                page.content.article.articlecontainer.articlescroller.articlebody
                            </div>
                            <div id="articlepullup" class="pullup">
                                page.nav.navcontrols.navcontainer.navscroller.articlepullup
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="articlefooter" class="footer">page.content.article.articlefooter</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ipad-landscape.css:

```
/* elements */
body
{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

div
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

ul
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}


/* classes */

.header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: Aqua;
}

.controls
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: Green;
}

.container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 636px; /* 768 minus header, controls and footer */
    background-color: Blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scroller
{
    width: 100%;
/*    height: 636px;*/
}

.trans
{
    /* transition */
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.nonselectable
{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.pulldown
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: Teal;
}

.items
{
    width: 100%;
}

.item
{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: Fuchsia;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.item:nth-child(2n+0)
{
    background-color: #efefef;
}

.bodycontent
{
    width: 100%;
}

.pullup
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: Teal;
}

.footer
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    background-color: Red;
}


/* identifiers */

#page
{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
}

#nav
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 768px;
}

#navheader
{
}

#navcontrols
{
}

#navcontainer
{
}

#navscroller
{
}

#navpulldown
{
}

#navitems
{
}

.navitem
{
    height: 44px;
}

#navpullup
{
}

#navfooter
{
}

#viewport
{
    width: 724px;
    height: 100%; /* CHANGING THIS VALUE TO 724px BREAKS THE SLIDING PANEL */
    background-color: Purple;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 1448px;
    height: 768px;
    background-color: Gray;
}

#list
{
    width: 724px;
    height: 768px;
}

#listheader
{
}

#listcontrols
{
}

#listcontainer
{
}

#listscroller
{
}

#listpulldown
{
}

#listitems
{
}

.listitem
{
    height: 88px;
}

#listpullup
{
}

#listfooter
{
}

#article
{
    width: 724px;
    height: 768px;
}

#articleheader
{
}

#articlecontrols
{
}

#articlecontainer
{
}

#articlescroller
{
}

#articlepulldown
{
}

#articlebody
{
}

#articlepullup
{
}

#articlefooter
{
}
```

Comment: FYI `margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;` is double redundant. Use `margin:0;`

Comment: Actually triple redundant in terms of selectors, too. `body, div, ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0} div, ul { position: relative; float: left;} ul {list-style-type: none}` cleans it up. ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, but this is definitely not finished code, hence the massive spaces. Anyone know a solution to the question?

Comment: It may be something with iScroll since it seems to work fine w/o it, also, if you set #viewport {overflow:visible} it works well for some reason, that may give you a lead. http://jsfiddle.net/Vervious/C3b8j/4/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by break, does it not work at all or does it not go all the way as you would like.

The #page height is 768, therefore currently your #viewport height (at 100%) is also 768.

Try putting 768 instead of 724 and see what happens (if it works the way you want).

I know this does not solve your question but it may reach closer to a solution.

Comment: Edited your answer to consistently say 768 (you have 786 in one place)

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by break is that on most browsers the sliding in of the right hand div does not animate, though it definitely happens in the DOM, because of the result of the moved element can be seen when doing things like scrolling it's content - ie: it happens. If the element had not been slid across it would not be visible at all.

Comment: Oh, btw, I have tried it with different heights. It seems that the issue is the use of px vs. %.